# How would you describe a bully turning and twisting his shoes on a victim's chest?

Tags: phrase-requests

Like the act itself. The thing that happens in nearly every movie involving a bully. The bully beats you down, then 'drills' his shoes into your chest. I'm looking for an alternative phrase to 'drilled his boots into...' or 'dug his feet into...' that takes into account the deliberate twisting and turning of the shoes.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the phrasal verb ***to grind <sub><sup>something</sup></sub> into <sub><sup>something</sup></sub>***

Defined by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grind-sth-into-sth) as:

> to press something hard into something else using a twisting movement:
> *Sara angrily ground her cigarette into the ashtray.*

The bully *ground* his foot into the small boy’s chest making him cry out in pain.